# Open device name using CreateFile

Tags: windows, winapi, driver

I am working on a simple device driver I want to comunicate with the driver from user-mode using IRP.

I am having trouble opening the device driver. Using [DeviceTree](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=97) I am able to see the device name eg \Device\MyDevice.

But when I try to open it like this :

```
hand := CreateFile('\Device\MyDevice', GENERIC_WRITE, 0, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
```

I always get `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` and GetLastError is (The System cannot find the path specified)

What I am doing wrong ? I know the driver works because I can see it running and printing stuff in DebugView. So any tips ?

[image]

Comment: I guess the path to the device is wrong. How have you checked it?

Comment: Shouldn't there be double backslash (`\\Device\MyDevice`) ?

Comment: @TLama I get network path not found that way

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes I checked it using DeviceTree see link above I will put a screen shot now

Comment: So you're probably at the same point as [`discussed here`](http://forum.sysinternals.com/createfile-unable-to-open-a-handle-to-a-device_topic15464.html).

Comment: @TLama already checked that thread the OP was missing a \ not my case here

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a good explanation by [Tim Robinson, MVP (Windows SDK)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/ivp76Pi9USw):

> Names of the form `\Device\xxx` are internal NT object manager names which are
>   inaccessible to Win32. You will only be able to access your device if it
>   creates a symbolic link to `\Device\MyDevice` from the `\??\` directory. Objects
>   in the `\??\` kernel directory show up through `\\.\` in Win32. Use Winobj in
>   the DDK (or download it from www.sysinternals.com) to check.

**NOTE**: Nowadays NT namespace root is exposed via `GLOBALROOT` symbolic link, so any NT path is accessible to Win32 including `\Device\xxx`: use `\\.\GLOBALROOT\Device\xxx`. A device symlink is not required in such case.

Comment: *You will only be able to access your device if it creates a symbolic link to \Device\MyDevice from the \??\ directory* - this is wrong. any symbolic link not need. and any NT path is **accessible** to win32, because exit `GLOBALROOT` symbolic link in *\GLOBAL??* to root of namespace. so we can access any path from win32 `CreateFileW` if append path with `"\\\\?\\Global\\GLOBALROOT"` or `"\\\\?\\GLOBALROOT"` (both is worked) so if we want access "\\Device\\xxx" - we can do this via "\\\\?\\GLOBALROOT\\Device\\xxx" name

Comment: @RbMm Nice and very important addition! Thanks!