# CreateFile and long device name

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, file-io

I'm using [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to open device. Everything is ok untill device name is too long.

In documentation it is said:

> In the ANSI version of this function, the name is limited to MAX_PATH characters. To extend this limit to 32,767 wide characters, call the Unicode version of the function and prepend "\\?\" to the path. For more information, see Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces.

I'm trying to use CreateFileW and prepend "\\?\" to the path, but getting invalid handle and

> The system cannot find the path specified.

in GetLastError().

So, is this trick valid only for filenames, not for device names? Are there any other ways to avoid this problem?

**UPD1:**
Device name without prepend looks like:

> \\.\devicename\EndsBy:\name1.exe|EndsBy:\name2.exe.

Code:

> CreateFileW(path.c_str(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING,          FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0));

Comment: Do you literally prepend `"\\?\"` or do you actually prepend `"\\\\?\\"`?

Comment: What does the device name actually look like? What does your code look like?

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast actually I prepend "\\\\?\\", also trying to prepend ""\\\\?" and some others.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind, `"\\?\"` requires an absolute path to follow.  It will also skip some normalization steps like processing `.` and `..`, or removing trailing dots and spaces.

Comment: Pleasr edit your question and include your code and other relevant information _there_ instead of in a comment.

Comment: So as far as I understood, according to @asveikau comment and according to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21704022/1541660, I have to use `"\\.\"` to access device and I can't prepand `"\\?\"` to path with long device name, because it doesn't work properly when path contains `.`. So trick with prepanding doesn't work dor devices, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\\?` prefix sends paths straight to the file-system with no preprocessing.

The `\\.` prefix bypasses the file namespace and uses the Win32 device namespace.

They have separate purposes and cannot be mixed together.

You can try this yourself.  For example, this will open the null device:

```
HANDLE hDevice = ::CreateFileW(L"\\\\.\\NUL", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
```

But if you change the path to `L"\\\\?\\\\.\\NUL"` it will fail.

To answer your question, yes, prefixing paths with `\\?` is only valid for file-system paths.

Comment: Note that you can open `\\?\NUL` rather than `\\.\NUL` (or at least it works on my system); do you happen to know what the rules are for when you can or can't replace the dot with the question mark?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I always assumed this was for backwards compatibility.  Devices that could be treated like files in DOS (NUL, COM1, LPT1, etc.) could also be treated like files in NT.  I've never investigated this in detail though, so I don't know if the file-system drivers recognise a hard-coded list of old DOS devices, or some more general class of devices.

Answer (score 2):

Some things to try:

- You can usually *replace* `\\.\` with `\\?\` ; it is my understanding that this will not always work, but I don't know what the rules are.
- If you're on Windows 8 try using [`CreateFile2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `\\.\` format; the documentation doesn't mention a path length limitation.
- Try contacting the vendor of the device driver, who should have realized that this would be a problem and hopefully has a workaround.
- Try using [`DefineDosDevice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create an alias for your long path, and opening `\\.\myalias` with `CreateFile`.  I'm not sure of the proper syntax for the path you're aliasing, but you can use `QueryDosDevice` to look at the existing aliases for guidance.  I believe you will want to use the `DDD_RAW_TARGET_PATH` flag.
- Failing all that, you may need to resort to [`NtCreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You should be able to use `CreateFile` to open `\\.\devicename` and then use that handle as the root directory for the call to `NtCreateFile`.  The downside here is that the API is not guaranteed to remain compatible in future versions of Windows.